# Рекурсия и указатели

Tags: c, указатели, рекурсия, codeblocks

Пишу одну рекурсивную функцию на C и решил вместо глобальной переменной, которая бы отвечала за остановку данной функции передавать в аргументе указатель на булеву переменную. Решил потренироваться на более простом примере:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(short unsigned int* q, short unsigned int N){
    if (N >= 5 || *q > 10){
            return 0;
    }
    else{
        *q = 1 + f(q, N+1);
        return *q;
    }
}

int main()
{
    short unsigned int* q;
    *q = 1;
    f(q, 1);
    printf("%u", *q);
}
```

Однако, программа не работает (В функции main я далее вывожу содержимое по адресу указателя, но в консоль программа ничего не выводит, а процесс завершается кодом -1073741819 (0xC0000005)). Помогите разобраться, в чём тут дело

Comment: Чтобы разобраться, нужна *вся программа*, а не кусок огрызка

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Вдруг вы передаете указатель в никуда, например?...

Comment: Извиняюсь, теперь привёл полный текст программы

Comment: Нужен не полный текст программы, а [mcve]

Comment: добро пожаловать в мир указателей, мир боли и страданий )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема вот тут:

```
    short unsigned int* q;
    *q = 1;
```

Вы неверно поняли работу с указателями - память под указатель нужно сперва зарезервировать, чего вы не делаете. Отсюда неопределенное поведение и все остальные эффекты.

Исправить можно как-то так:

```
int main()
{
    short unsigned int q = 1;
    f(&q, 1);
    printf("%u", q);
}
```

Здесь важно понимать, что мы берем память на стеке под переменную q, после чего используем указатель на нее в функции.

Comment: Минусующие, вы знаете что делать - пишите комментарии.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я почему-то совсем забыл про такую вещь, как выделение памяти

Comment: ну тут автор вопроса (ответ я считаю вполне адекватный, поставил ему плюсик) сам виноват, нужно было попросить не только исправить ошибку, но и написать, что должно вывестись в консоль. ну чтоб вы понимали, на кодеблоке программируют школьники (там онлайн школа на нем). поэтому не стоит слишком строго к ним относится.